# Enable null values when assigning one collection to other in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I wrote to following controller to assign one collection to another

```
    public ActionResult Discussion_List() {

        var discussions = (from D in db.AB_Discussion
                           select new
                           {

                           Discussion_ID = D.Discussion_ID,
                           Discussion_Name = D.Discussion_Name,
                           CreatedBy = D.CreatedBy,
                           CreatedDate = D.CreatedDate,
                           UpdatedBy  =  D.UpdatedBy,
                           UpdatedDate =  D.UpdatedDate

                           }).ToList();

        var models = discussions.Select(b => new Discussion_Dashboard()

        {
            Discussion_ID = b.Discussion_ID,
            Discussion_Name = b.Discussion_Name,
            CreatedBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(b.CreatedBy).UserName,
            CreatedDate = b.CreatedDate,
            UpdatedBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(b.UpdatedBy).UserName,
            UpdatedDate = b.UpdatedDate

        });

        return View(models);
    }
```

but when I have null values in any one of above field in database table *AB_Discussion* I'm getting following error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How to avoid this error

this is my related model classes

```
   public partial class Discussion_Dashboard
    {
        public int Discussion_ID { get; set; }
        public string Discussion_Name { get; set; }
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public int Views { get; set; }

        public int replys { get; set; }

    }

   public partial class AB_Discussion
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Discussion_ID { get; set; }
        public string Discussion_Name { get; set; }
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating the first collection of anonymous objects? - it can just be `var discussions = (from D in db.AB_Discussion select D).ToList();`

Comment: since I want to find username by ID i pass this to another

Comment: Your just creating another collection which is identical to your existing collection (its pointless)

Comment: but then How can I find username in firstplace ?

Comment: Which properties are `null` (I assume just the `UpdatedBy`)?

Comment: yes exactly updateby and update data null when new one create

Comment: `UpdatedBy = b.UpdatedBy == null ? null : db.AspNetUsers.Find(b.UpdatedBy).UserName,`

Comment: ohhh thats works , thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use a mapper, for example the [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) that you can find on GitHub or install via NuGet. The AutoMapper helps you map one class to another in a relatively easy way with reasonable defaults for fields with the same name and so on.

If you want to allow null values you can just define that using the ? operator right after the type in your variable declaration, for example:

```
public int? views { get; set; }
```

This will give your variable a public readonly property HasValue that you can use to see whether your variable contains a value or not.

Comment: what the syntax for strings ?

Comment: The syntax is the same, just replace 'int?' with 'string?'